# Conditional independence testing with generalized covariance measure

Tags: st.statistics

I am trying to understand the arxiv paper "[The Hardness of Conditional Independence Testing and the Generalized Covariance Measure](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07203)", specifically the use of the generalized covariance measure as a test of conditional independence. I understand the proofs of its properties, but don't see how those imply a test with a specific power?

EDIT: If you prefer the published version it's [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-48/issue-3/The-hardness-of-conditional-independence-testing-and-the-generalised-covariance/10.1214/19-AOS1857.short).